# Twitters iPhone NavBar Logo

Tags: iphone, twitter, uinavigationbar

This is more like a design question but does anyone know how they made the Logo in the UINavigationBar look that good in the native iPhone app?

[image: Twitter]

Does anyone know a tutorial?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you provide an image of what you mean?

Comment: Edited my question with a link to the example I'm talking about!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically both answers were correct.

I'm just typing the code I've used. I like it better than @stevenhepting 's code :)

Just put this code in the `viewDidLoad:` method

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourPicture"]];
```

The perfect size for your image (in my opinion) is 80x40 pixels (width=80 / height=40).

Answer (score 1):

A UIViewController's -navigationItem property has itself a property called -titleView.

Set that titleView property of the currently displayed UIViewController's navigationItem to an embossed, semi-transparent icon like Twitter has done, and you're set.

Answer (score 0):

You will load an image, and then put it in the navigationItem.titleView property on the view controller that will be inside the navigation controller.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"header_logo.png"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: image];
viewController.navigationItem.titleView = imageView;
```